# Making custom currency

Tags: pdf, formatting

I've been using Prawn (Ruby) to make signs for beer distributors. Working great except that making currency look how I want is becoming *extremely* cumbersome and I'm afraid of inflexibility (and head pounding) later on when expanding. Enter LaTeX.

Here's what I'm shooting for:

[image: Price example]

Being a complete newbie with LaTeX, I thought about

```
\textsuperscript{\$}5\textsuperscript{99}
```

and maybe resize the cents and dollar symbol along with changing the baseline to lower them? What's best way to accomplish this?

And for a bonus question: looking at what I'm making, would LaTeX be a good choice? Resizing different types text to fit a certain area is also a huge pain with my current setup. Thanks and sorry for all the questions!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)    Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire.

    As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: To answer your bonus questions: I wouldn't use LaTeX for signs like that. Using some desktop publishing software or vector graphic editor like Inkscape would be easier if you just have some images, some minor text and a price tag.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, I fixed the image tag. Also, we make about 300-400 different kinds of signs a month (per distributor) so we need to automate the making of these. That's why I use Ruby/Prawn currently. Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look on [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) then. I would create it as diagrams, not using text macros.

Answer (score 1):

To answer first your bonus question: like Martin, I'm in doubt, if it is usefull to use LaTeX for tasks like this.

First, you should do something like markup definition. Define a macro, so you can adapt your code in a central place. In my example I define \price with three parameters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\price[3]{
%  \textsuperscript{#1}#2\textsuperscript{#3}
\raisebox{0.2ex}{\scriptsize #1}%
#2%
\raisebox{0.2ex}{\scriptsize #3}%
}

\price{\$}{5}{99}

\price{\euro}{5}{99}
\end{document}
```

In my test it looks quite good. But depending on the selected font, you may need to change the values. That's one of the reasons, where LaTeX isn't the best solution. LaTeX is made for typesetting, not 'design'.